# Python Json loops

Tags: python, json, for-loop

I am trying to parse a JSON page in Python, it is contained in a variable reddit_front.
I am trying to get the sum of all "ups" in this page. I do have the right answer which is the following:

```
def total_ups():
    j=json.loads(reddit_front)
    return sum(c["data"]["ups"] for c in j["data"]["children"])
```

However why does the following loop give me only 1 item and not iterate over?

```
def total_ups():
    j=json.loads(reddit_front)
    for c in j["data"]["children"]:
        i = c["data"]["ups"]
        a = +i
        return a
```

PS: ok, all good points and thx for the negative reputations points, it's fair call I wasn't precise in my question.

Comment: A program is buggy only if it doesn't do what it is expected to do. It's a problem here is that we don't know what do you expect from this code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe...

```
def total_ups():
    children = json.loads(reddit_front)["data"]["children"]
    return sum(c["data"]["ups"] for c in children)
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but since he didn't show what it should output or anything I tried to keep it like he originally had it, though this does improve how the code looks.

Comment: @user2925490 yea, this code may indeed look a bit weird for those who don't understand list comprehensions/generators but this is the pythonic way. :-)

Comment: Yes, that's the right answer but I was trying to understand why the original code doesn't work. Thx

Comment: @Bondifrench The original code doesn't work because you return from the whole function in the first iteration of your for loop so the for loop processes only the first "ups" item. Your `return a` is inside the for loop, maybe you are not used to the "indented blocks" of python. Your code will also work if you 1.) initialize a to zero before the for loop 2.) you write `a += i` instead of `a = +i` 3.) you remove a level of indentation from your `return a` statement to move it out from the for loop (after the for loop).

Comment: Thx @pasztorpisti that's a very complete answer! and yes, i'm still a beginner in Python, indentations are often confusing me.

Comment: @Bondifrench You will love it after 1-2 months. I was also confused as I started to learn python after C-family languages and I just didn't find my `{` and `}` characters in python. :-) Indentation helps to make all people's code to look similar and doesn't let you to write ugly esoterically indented/blocked code. It also helps you in typing less when you are writing your few-liner helper/automatizer scripts.

Answer (score 2):

`return` will stop the loop, try appending it to a list then you can join it or whatever you need to so you can get the data.

Example:

```
def total_ups():
    a = list()
    j=json.loads(reddit_front)
    for c in j["data"]["children"]:
        i = c["data"]["ups"]
        a.append(+i)
    return a
print(total_ups()) # returns list
print(", ".join(total_ups)) # returns a string separated by commas
```